# How to access value in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have The following list of dictionaries:

```
d =  [(u'Code', u'US'), (u'Country', u'United States'), (u'Name', u'Bill')]
```

How do I access the values of the individual Dictionaries?

```
eg. d['Code'] gives 'US' - obviously does not work
```

Comment: There are no dictionaries in your code.

Comment: Those aren't dictionaries in your `list`, they are [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Comment: This a list of tuples

Comment: Sorry guys - Bonehead mistake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not a list of dictionaries; it is a list of two-item tuples:

```
>>> d =  [(u'Code', u'US'), (u'Country', u'United States'), (u'Name', u'Bill')]
>>> type(d)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(d[0])
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

If you want `d` to be converted into a dictionary, place it in [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
>>> d =  [(u'Code', u'US'), (u'Country', u'United States'), (u'Name', u'Bill')]
>>> d = dict(d)
>>> d
{'Code': 'US', 'Name': 'Bill', 'Country': 'United States'}
>>> d['Code']
'US'
>>>
```